# WebView page loading failed after webviewglue: nativeDestroy view

Tags: android, webview

I have following problem on some Android devices (I can reproduce it now on Galaxy Note II and Galaxy S4):
A WebView is not able to load a page. There is no error or onReceivedError call, but the onPageFinished is not fired too. I implemented the progress callback to see if the page is loading. Following stays in the log:

```
11-11 17:15:23.380 D/WebView (14099): loadUrlImpl: called
11-11 17:15:23.395 V/webkit  (14099): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {424c9b48}
11-11 17:15:23.420 D/webcore (14099):  CORE loadUrl: called
11-11 17:15:23.420 E/SQLiteLog(14099): (1) no such table: CacheGroups
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): ERROR:
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM CacheGroups" error "no such table: CacheGroups"
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099):
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
11-11 17:15:23.425 E/SQLiteLog(14099): (1) no such table: Caches
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): ERROR:
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Caches" error "no such table: Caches"
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099):
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
11-11 17:15:23.425 E/SQLiteLog(14099): (1) no such table: Origins
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): ERROR:
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Origins" error "no such table: Origins"
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099):
11-11 17:15:23.425 D/WebKit  (14099): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
11-11 17:15:23.425 E/SQLiteLog(14099): (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
11-11 17:15:23.505 E/de.my.app.webview.MyWebChromeClient(14099): Progress: 10
11-11 17:15:24.205 E/de.my.app.webview.MyWebChromeClient(14099): Progress: 30
11-11 17:15:24.210 E/de.my.app.webview.MyWebChromeClient(14099): Progress: 49
11-11 17:15:24.985 E/de.my.app.webview.MyWebChromeClient(14099): Progress: 68
11-11 17:15:28.035 D/dalvikvm(14099): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1905K, 6% free 53808K/56967K, paused 13ms+17ms, total 69ms
11-11 17:15:28.085 D/webviewglue(14099): nativeDestroy view: 0x62e7e6a8
11-11 17:15:28.535 I/GATE    (14099): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

It works fine on other test devices. Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason was, that I have a WebView pre-loader that shows the WebView if it is done with loading and send a callback message. The WebView itself was not assigned to a variable and was removed by the garbage collector on some devices.

Comment: Can you explain it? how to fix this. I encountered similar problem using Phonegap on certain android devices, really annoying.

Comment: @user2412555 I don't use PhoneGap in my project, but I saw some similar issues with PhoneGap when I was searching for a solution. But in my case it was so: I have a WebViewWrapper class that is the listener for all WebView callbacks and sends a callback to the caller if the WebView is loaded. I initialized a WebViewWrapper only with  new WebViewWrapper(this); without setting it to a variable. During the WebView load process came the GC and released the instance and the WebView itself with it.

Comment: In this case you need to set it for example to a instance variable and let it live until the page is loaded.